# JUnit 5 (Jupiter) Testcases in eclipse projects not being run

Tags: java, eclipse, junit5, test-suite

I have an eclipse workspace (version 2019-12, non-maven) with multiple web projects, all containing java code, and some referencing each other. At the end of the reference 'graph' is a project dedicated to contain a test suite, which in turn is supposed to reference all other projects' tests.
All projects export their test-source folders. (All test classes are visible to the downstream projects).

I started to define the following suite:

```java
package platformTest;

import org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasses;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import de.***.PlatformEnvironmentTestcases;
import de.***.ClientTestcases;

@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@SelectClasses({
    PlatformEnvironmentTestcases.class,
    ClientTestcases.class
}) 
public class JUnit5TestSuite {
    // test suite
}
```

However the referenced test classes (though successfully running on their own, and being directly referenced) are not being executed at all.

I tried:

- setting the debug config to junit4, with the result that no tests are executed. It seems the compatibility layer between junit 4 and 5 is not working here.
- setting the debug config to junit5, with the result that a message window pops up: "No tests found with test runner 'JUnit 5'.
- setting the debug config to junit5 and selecting 'Run all tests in the selected project, package or folder:' which - surprisingly - is working, but I cannot select the workspace root, which means I can never select all projects, and this setup will only find the tests in the suit's project and the selected project, but not the rest.

I found multiple bugs referenced for older versions of eclipse displaying similar symptoms, but since I am running a very recent version, I suppose those should not apply anymore. Also I tried most of the workarounds suggested without success.

Comment: @RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class) together with all the Select-annotations is used to run JUnit 5 projects through JUnit 4. They DO NOT WORK with JUnit 5 platform support.

Comment: Ah... is there a way to go all JUnit5? Since all my projects are own projects, all my tests are junit5.

Comment: What do you want the test suite class use for? Running tests across several projects? For that purpose most people use Maven or Gradle.

Comment: The intention is to have one project binding several others and that project should contain a suite running all testcases of all projects.

Comment: In that case I recommend a Gradle or Maven multi module project.

Comment: I might go with that, though I tried to avoid shooting with big cannons on a small problem. But lacking alternatives, I may have to go with maven. If not that, then I might go back to JUnit 4, since that works (for a funny fact) perfectly well, and as of right now I don't need the JUnit5 platform features. But I tried to be compliant with JUnit5 to keep that door open.